# For a square matrix A over $\mathbb{C}$, Proofs that matrices D and N exist with A=D+N under different conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

(i) D is Diagonalizable

This one i believe to be fairly straightforward, if D is diagonalizable then we can allow $D^t = I$ (where I is the identity) and therefore D id diagonalizable and therefore A=N+D is straightforward.

(ii)N is Nilpotent

So when there exists an r such that $N^r=0$

(iii)DN = ND

Each one seems rather trivial, e.g for (ii) D could be any square matrix of the same size as N and it be a Square matrix A and for (iii) you just prove commutativity for matrices?

I believe I'm missing something quite important here but can't figure out what

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying we need to satisfy all three conditions simultaneously?

Comment: @Joe I misunderstood the question i believed it would be seperate but it means simultaneously, still not sure how to do the question though haha

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I A is a square matrix over $\mathbb{C}$, Prove there are matrices D and N such that A=D+N such that...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3068934/i-a-is-a-square-matrix-over-mathbbc-prove-there-are-matrices-d-and-n-such)

Answer (score 1):

First: I'm very sure that you've entirely misunderstood the question, and you need to find $D$ and $N$ such that **all** of these conditions hold at once. I'll edit a proof of that question into this answer later today, if nobody beats me to it.

> This one i believe to be fairly straightforward, if D is diagonalizable then we can allow Dt=I (where I is the identity) and therefore D id diagonalizable and therefore A=N+D is straightforward.

I have no idea what you mean here, but if you're only trying to find $D$ satisfying this condition, just take $D$ to be the identity.

> (ii)N is Nilpotent
>   So when there exists an r such that $N^r=0$

Again, if you only wanted this, just take $N = 0$.

> Each one seems rather trivial, e.g for (ii) D could be any square matrix of the same size as N and it be a Square matrix A and for (iii) you just prove commutativity for matrices?

You could try, but matrix multiplication isn't commutative, so you would fail.

---

Comment: I think you're right thank you, forgot about commutivity as well oops! Just at a quick glance would it be wrong to say N = 0 and D = I as then ND = 0 = DN, and a single example would suffice to answer the question

Comment: Yes: you also need $N + D = A$, and your proof should hold for any $A$.

Comment: Right I'm not entirely sure where to start but I'll give it a go, thanks for pointing out my misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably missing here is that all conditions should hold simultanously. You can not choose D=I because than A-D=N would not necessarily be nilpotent. Also, commutativity for matrices is not something that always holds!

Comment: Yes you're right, i believe i have and that's also a schoolboy error i've made! Thanks!