# Proof of Jordan-Chevalley decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, matrix-decomposition, nilpotence

> Let $A$ be a square matrix over $\mathbb{C}$. Prove there are matrices $D$ and $N$ such that $A = D + N$ such that $D$ is diagonalizable, $N$ is nilpotent and $DN = ND$.

I can see that any nilpotent matrix has to satisfy $N^l=0$ for some $l$. I'm not sure how to go about proving that all these conditions hold for any square matrix A.

Comment: Look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan–Chevalley_decomposition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***"Intuition":***
We construct $D$ and $N$ in the following fashion: We want to show, that for any invertible matrix $S \in \text{GL}(n,K)$ we have
$$
A = S^{-1} \tilde{D} S + S^{-1} ( J(A) - \tilde{D}) S,
$$
where $J(A)$ is the Jordan decomposition of $A$.

This is true because from Jordan decomposition we that the exists an invertible matrix $S \in \text{GL}(n,K)$, so that
\begin{align*}
A = S^{-1} J(A) S
= S^{-1} (\tilde{D} + J(A) - \tilde{D}) S
= S^{-1} \tilde{D} S + S^{-1} ( J(A) - \tilde{D}) S.
\end{align*}

***Existence:***
Let $\tilde{D}$ be the diagonal matrix whose entries are the eigenvalues of $A$.
Because every diagonalisable matrix is similar to a diagonal matrix, we know, that $S^{-1} \tilde{D} S$ is diagonalisable und let $D := S^{-1} \tilde{D} S$.

Now $J(A) - \tilde{D}$ is a upper triangular matrix, whose diagonal only contains zeros and therefore nilpotent.
Also, $N := S^{-1}( J(A) - \tilde{D}) S$ is nilpotent and we have $A = D + N$.

***Commutativity:***

Because $\tilde{D}$ is a diagonal matrix we have
\begin{align*}
DN
& = S^{-1} \tilde{D} S S^{-1} ( J(A) - \tilde{D}) S
= S^{-1} \tilde{D} ( J(A) - \tilde{D}) S
= S^{-1} ( J(A) - \tilde{D}) \tilde{D} S \\
& = S^{-1} ( J(A) - \tilde{D}) S S^{-1} \tilde{D} S
= ND
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

A good thing to remember is that complex numbers form an algebraically closed field. So A is similar to a triangular matrix. So I think you can narrow your proof by only proving the result for a triangular matrix and concluding by using similarity.